# Reference to a dynamically allocated variable vs Pointer to the same dynamically allocated variable?

Tags: c++

**Case-1:**

```
int* func1() {
    return new int;
}
```

**Case-2:**

```
int& func2() {
    return *(new int);
}
```

Yes, the return value of one needs to be stored in a pointer variable and the other in an int variable and they both are equally likely to create a memory leak if we forget to deallocate the memory in heap.

So, for all practial purposes, they are equivalent, right?

Comment: **Case-3:** `std::unique_ptr<int> func3() { return std::make_unique<int>(); }`

Comment: @NickyC: What's that? What's a unique_ptr?

Comment: It is a ownership smart pointer provided by the Standard Library. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Comment: If dynamic allocation is necessary, smart pointer should be the default choice of interface.

Comment: @NickyC: Never heard of that before but will look it up. Thanks a lot for bringing it to my notice. :)

Answer (score 3):

No, the two are not equivalent from the point of view of readability: when you return a pointer, readers of your code think about the ownership of that pointer; when you return a reference, they know for sure that you own it.

It is natural for users of your API to delete a pointer that you return. Your API documentation needs to say whether the pointer needs to be deleted with `delete[]` or `delete`, - or not at all, in cases when your library retains the ownership of the object that you return by pointer.

It is entirely unnatural for users of your API to think that they may need to delete anything returned to them by reference. It does not mean that you cannot do it - you certainly can, but it would be completely unexpected, so one should avoid doing it.

Comment: More subtle, what type should one select for a formal argument that carries an argument object to some code that stores its address somewhere. I tend to use pointers in such cases, even though a pointer *technically* can be a nullpointer. I.e. I think it's more important to communicate "this is used as a storable *value* that refers to the object" rather than communicating "this should be a valid object reference". Maybe one should define a special kind of pointer wrapper? I do agree with your viewpoint that what's communicated to the reader is more important than technical equivalence.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Well, actually, a pointer need not always point to a dynamically created variable. It can even hold the address of a variable on stack, in which case, deleting it would cause undesirable results. So, there would be ambiguity either way, right?

Comment: @TheVigilanteSting That's what I said about pointers in the second sentence of the second paragraph. The documentation specifies what you do with the pointer - whether you delete it or not. References, on the other hand, do not imply a need to be deleted.

Comment: Ok, you're on a whole different level right now. What documentation? If it's the program description, I'm sure we can just as well specify to delete the reference if needed by using comments. Please clarify. I'm a rookie.

Comment: @TheVigilanteSting A library (or a class library, it does not matter) comes with API documentation, similar to the documentation of the Standard C++ library, but for your code. It is often, but not always, generated from comments of special format using tools similar to doxygen. Whenever an API returns a pointer, the documentation should say who "owns it", i.e. who is responsible for freeing it.

Comment: Dear dasblinkenlight, thanks for explaining. I really like you. I shall pray for you and your family tonight. :)

Comment: @TheVigilanteSting: a key point here is that when a programmer sees a function declaration like `int& func2();` they'll assume that they do not need to use `delete`, because *nobody* returns dynamically allocated objects as object references, whereas if they see the `int*` version they'll know there's an open question about who is responsible for deallocation and that their best bet of finding out is documentation or implementation.  That's one reason why returning a smart pointer is better - it not only documents ownership semantics locally, but the compiler enforces correct usage.

Answer (score 1):

If the compiler is smart enough, the two cases may compile to the same machine code (my compiler does, at least), for example:

```
int* func1() {
    return new int;
    /*
    push $04
    call $00402afe
    pop ecx
    */
}

int& func2() {
    return *(new int);
    /*
    push $04
    call $00402afe
    pop ecx
    */
}
```

Other than the possibility of maybe having slightly different machine code being generated by the compiler if the second case's de-referencing/re-referencing is not optimized away, they are essentially equivalent in that the caller ends up receiving a memory address to the allocated `int` value in both cases.  From a technical standpoint, pointers and references are treated identical in machine code, the main difference is that the compiler validates that a reference is never unassigned but a pointer can be.  But from a coding standpoint, pointers and references are different beasts with different coding semantics, rules of use, etc.